# unchecked cast warning on Collection

Tags: java

I am mapping a postgres array_agg value to a list, but I'm getting a warning below
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>
What is the fix for this?

```
public UserDTO transformTuple(Object[] objects, String[] strings) {
    List<String> roleList = new ArrayList<>((Collection<String>)objects[7]);
```

Comment: Does it work at runtime?

Comment: I don't see a guarantee that everything in `objects` is actually a `String`. You could use the no-argument constructor for `roleList`, or the constructor specifying an initial capacity.   Then, move elements of `objects` using a `for` loop, checking each time the element is actually a `String` before casting it and adding it to `roleList`.

Comment: Uh, Is the '7' in 'objects[7]' a typo made when posting the question,  or is that actually part of your code?  In your code, that would result in an attempt to cast a single `java.lang.Object` to a `java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>'.

Comment: The [7] is not a typo, since it is an array.. although for more simplicity I could've made that a [0]

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Custom Types so that your java application can map postgresql data type into your application, I assume you are using hibernate in this scenario so here is a reference [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types) for further details.

And here other link reference you can look

[Using Java arrays to insert, retrieve, & update PostgreSQL arrays](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/using-java-arrays-insert-retrieve-update-postgresql-arrays)

[PostgreSQL Array](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-array/)